# Paginating a FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to be able to create "reports" as regular MVVM views, so to test this idea I created the following view. It just consists of a bound textblock, an ItemsControl (bound to a collection of a few hundred strings), and a second text block:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myListItemTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                       Foreground="Blue" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <FlowDocument x:Name="flowDoc">
        <BlockUIContainer>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" />
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myListItemTemplate}" />
                <TextBlock Text="THE END" />
            </StackPanel>
        </BlockUIContainer>
    </FlowDocument>
</UserControl>
```

I print the view using a DocumentPaginator like this:

```
    private void Print(IPrintableView view)
    {
        var dlg = new PrintDialog();
        if (!dlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            return;
        }

        var paginator = new MyDocumentPaginator(
            view.FlowDocument,
            new Size(dlg.PrintableAreaWidth, dlg.PrintableAreaHeight),
            new Size(DefaultMarginWidthDpi, DefaultMarginHeightDpi));

        dlg.PrintDocument(paginator, "My print job");
    }
```

Unsurprisingly the document isn't being paginated, and produce a 1-page report that gets truncated partway through the list. (I don't believe my document paginator implementation is important here, which simply adds a header and footer to each page, and I see the same issue if I use the FlowDocument's own FlowDocumentPaginator).

As I now understand it, document paginators will only break on "[Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.block?view=netframework-4.6.1&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Documents.Block)%3Bk(vs.objectbrowser)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.6.1)%26rd%3Dtrue)" controls, so I modified the xaml to wrap each control in a `BlockUIContainer`:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myListItemTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                       Foreground="Blue" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <FlowDocument x:Name="flowDoc">
        <BlockUIContainer>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" />
        </BlockUIContainer>
        <BlockUIContainer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myListItemTemplate}" />
        </BlockUIContainer>
        <BlockUIContainer>
            <TextBlock Text="THE END" />
        </BlockUIContainer>
    </FlowDocument>
</UserControl>
```

Here, a page break now occurs after the first TextBlock, with the list starting on page 2 (but still being truncated at the end of that page), and the second textblock appearing on page 3.

I assume the paginator is measuring and rendering the entire ItemsControl as a whole, so I then tried placing each list item inside a BlockUIContainer via the ItemContainerStyle:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <BlockUIContainer>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
                    </BlockUIContainer>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This made no difference though. Is there a way to get this working? Am I even approaching this in the right way? Placing every UI control inside a "block" seems very cumbersome, especially when it the time comes to implement a real report containing a lot of complexity. The real reports won't necessarily be list based either, and are more likely to contain a mixture of controls - text, images, lists, etc. in a fairly free-style layout (more web page than banded report).

Answer (score 0):

So this wasn't straightforward as I was expecting, and if it were not for stumbling across [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/april/create-flexible-uis-with-flow-documents-and-data-binding#id0420102) then I'd probably never have found a solution. In the article, the author has created a series of classes and controls including a "FlowDocument friendly" list, with the option of rendering it as a Table, meaning that page breaks will occur between the items' TableRows when necessary.

Here's my updated "report view" xaml. Note that I've also refactored the text by using a `<Paragraph>` rather than a TextBlock inside a BlockUIElement. You'll also notice that these Paragraphs are also bindable, via a custom `BindableRun` control that is also part of the above article:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <FlowDocument x:Name="flowDoc"
                  TextElement.FontFamily="Arial">
        <Paragraph Margin="0,0,0,20">
            <flowDocuments:BindableRun BoundText="{Binding Message}" />
        </Paragraph>

        <flowDocuments:ItemsContent ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}">
            <flowDocuments:ItemsContent.ItemsPanel>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <flowDocuments:Fragment>
                        <Table>
                            <Table.Columns>
                                <TableColumn Width="*" />
                            </Table.Columns>
                            <TableRowGroup flowDocuments:Attached.IsItemsHost="True">
                                <TableRow Background="LightBlue">
                                    <TableCell>
                                        <Paragraph>Heading</Paragraph>
                                    </TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableRowGroup>
                        </Table>
                    </flowDocuments:Fragment>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flowDocuments:ItemsContent.ItemsPanel>
            <flowDocuments:ItemsContent.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <flowDocuments:Fragment>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <flowDocuments:BindableRun BoundText="{Binding}" />
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </flowDocuments:Fragment>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flowDocuments:ItemsContent.ItemTemplate>
        </flowDocuments:ItemsContent>

        <Paragraph>THE END</Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</UserControl>
```

The custom `ItemsContent` control is used to render the list, and has a few familiar properties:

- an `ItemsSource` property for binding to the VM's collection
- an `ItemTemplate` property defining a DataTemplate that consists of a "Fragment" element (again from the above article), and within *this* a `<TableRow>` used to render the string items in my VM's collection
- an `ItemsPanel`, used to define the "container" - in this case a `Table` control. This example includes a hardcoded TableRow used to display the column headings. I believe other containers are permitted such as a , although I didn't read the article in detail.

Anyway, it all appears to work, and produces a report that is correctly paginated, with the list of strings breaking to new pages at the correct places.

If anyone else uses the article to generate reports as I have done, be aware that the `ItemsContent` Loaded event never fires, resulting in the list not rendering (this is presumably due to the way I'm programmatically creating the view and/or not displaying it on screen). To get it working, I had to comment out the three `if (IsLoaded)` lines that appear later on in this class.